# Setting Testng parameter to be value of another parameter

Tags: java, testng

I use Testng xml to configure parameters for my tests.

Different users may have different parameters in the xml files, and I want avoid duplicating xml code.

The idea is that each user defines a suite with needed parameters:

```
<suite name="Patrick's test file">

 <parameter name="favoriteApple" value="gala"/>
 <parameter name="favoriteGrape" value="red"/>

 <suite-file>
   <suite-file path="test.xml"/>
 </suite-file>

</suite>
```

Note that other users may have a different test file with different values for favoriteApple and favoriteGrape.
The test.xml looks like this:

```
<suite name="test">

 <test>
   <parameter name="fruit" value="VALUE OF favoriteApple PARAMETER"/>
   <packages>
     <package name="apple fruit test"/>
   </packages>
 </test>

 <test>
   <parameter name="fruit" value="VALUE OF favoriteGrape PARAMETER"/>
   <packages>
     <package name="grape fruit test"/>
   </packages>
 </test>

</suite>
```

The motivation for the test structure is that each package has a class which extends an abstract class. The abstract class has a setup method @BeforeTest which takes in the parameter into protected members.

I have not found a way to set the values of parameters to be the value of another parameter.

Right now everyone needs to have an xml file with duplicated code for the tests.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way for implementation of listener other than the one provided in the other answer.

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class CustomListen3 extends TestListenerAdapter {
    /**
     * Invoked after test class in initialized and before all the getters and
     * setters are called.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // Get the current test
        XmlTest currentTest = context.getCurrentXmlTest();
        // Get all the parameters Global and local
        Map<String, String> parameters = currentTest.getAllParameters();
        for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
            String parameterValue = parameters.get(key);
            // If parameter value starts with $, replace with the global parameter value
            if (parameterValue.startsWith("$")) {
                String newValue = currentTest.getParameter(parameterValue.substring(1));
                Assert.assertNotNull(newValue, "Global parameter value, " + parameterValue.substring(1));
                parameters.put(key, newValue);
            }
        }
        // Update the new parameters
        currentTest.setParameters(parameters);
        super.onStart(context);
    }
}
```

- This requires lesser code
- @BeforeTest method need not be invoked again

The only small issue is that the local parameter value is over written by the global parameter value.

Comment: I was hoping that this was a feature of Testng that I missed but this will due as a workaround. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by following the below steps

- Introduce a concept of global parameters which are provided in the global_suite.xml file.
- The reference to these global parameters should then be provided in the individual test files using a character like `$`.
- if a parameter value starts with `$`, testNG should look for a global parameter. This implementation should be made in a `custom listener`.
- If the `$` symobol is not used, then the parameter value will be used as is. This gives the flexibility to run test.xml without the global suite file as well

**global_suite.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Sighil's test file">
    <parameter name="favoriteApple" value="gala" />
    <parameter name="favoriteGrape" value="red" />
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="path to CustomListen"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="testng_3.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="test" parallel="none">
    <test verbose="2" name="AppleTest" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="fruit" value="$favoriteApple" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.project.ppp.AppleTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test verbose="2" name="GrapeTest" enabled="true">
        <parameter name="fruit" value="$favoriteGrape" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.project.ppp.GrapeTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**CustomListen.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener2;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class CustomListen implements IInvokedMethodListener2 {
    @Override public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod invokedMethod, ITestResult testResult) {}
    @Override public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod invokedMethod, ITestResult testResult) {}
    @Override public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod invokedMethod, ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context) {}

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod invokedMethod, ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context) {
        ITestNGMethod testNGMethod = invokedMethod.getTestMethod();
        XmlTest currentTest = context.getCurrentXmlTest();
        // if method invoked is setFruit
        if (testNGMethod.isBeforeTestConfiguration() && testNGMethod.getMethodName().equals("setFruit")) {
            // find the java.lang.reflect method
            Method method = testNGMethod.getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
            // Get the parameters defined setFruit
            Parameters parameter = method.getAnnotation(Parameters.class);
            if (parameter != null) {
                // get the parameter names
                String[] parameterNames = parameter.value();
                // initiate a String array to hold the parameter values
                String[] parameterValues = new String[parameterNames.length];
                boolean setNewParameterValue = false;
                // loop the parameter names to get their corresponding parameter values
                for (int index = 0; index < parameterNames.length; index++) {
                    // set the parameter value
                    parameterValues[index] = currentTest.getParameter(parameterNames[index]);

                    // check if parameter value set expects a global parameter value
                    if (parameterValues[index].startsWith("$")) {
                        String newParameterValue = currentTest.getParameter(parameterValues[index].substring(1));
                        // Check if global parameter value is set
                        Assert.assertNotNull(newParameterValue,
                                "Global parameter name, " + parameterValues[index].substring(1));
                        parameterValues[index] = newParameterValue;
                        setNewParameterValue = true;
                    }
                }
                // invoke the setFruit BeforeTest method again to set the protected members if
                // global parameters are required
                if (setNewParameterValue) {
                    try {
                        method.invoke(testResult.getInstance(), (Object[]) parameterValues);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the above on **TestNG 6.14.3** with the below classes

```
public class GrapeTest extends FruitTest {
    @Test
    public void grapeTest() {
        System.out.println("grapeTest - " + fruit);
    }
}

public class AppleTest extends FruitTest {
    @Test
    public void appleTest() {
        System.out.println("appleTest - " + fruit);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite

appleTest - gala
grapeTest - red
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.493 sec - in TestSuite
```